# iOS 17 crash with presenting modal view controller on itself using deprecated keyWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uipopoverpresentationcontroller, keywindow

Since the upgrade from iOS 15 to iOS 17, my iPad app has been crashing when I try to display modal popovers with the following error and I am unable to resolve the issue:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <VolumeVC: 0x7fc81882c520>.'
```

For context, I've been using the following utility class throughout my app to first get the top most view controller in the window so that I can then display a modal popover with a view controller in it.

**Utility.m**

```
+ (UIViewController*)topViewController {
        
    UIViewController *topVC = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
    NSLog(@"Utility::topViewController(): topVC is: %@", topVC);
    
    int countLoops = 0;
    while (topVC.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
        NSLog(@"Utility::topViewController(): In loop, topVC is: %@, countLoops is: %i", topVC, countLoops);
        countLoops++;
        if (countLoops > 25) { break; }
    } 
    return topVC;
}

+ (void)showDialogiPad:(UIViewController *)contentVC
       fromPresentingVC:(UIViewController *)presentingVC
                 inView:(UIView *)view
                atFrame:(CGRect)frame
          withDirection:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)direction {
    
    // Choose the presentation style in which the content is displayed in a popover view
    contentVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    
    // Set the popover size, anchor location and direction
    contentVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = frame;
    contentVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = view;
    contentVC.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = direction;
   
    // Set the arrow direction for the popover
    popoverVC.permittedArrowDirections = direction;
    
    // Present the popover presentation controller
    [presentingVC presentViewController:contentVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

An example of how this gets called from elsewhere in the code is the following:

```
    // Show the volume view controller in a popover
    [Utility showDialogiPad:volumeVC // volumeVC is a simple view controller I want to show in the popup
        fromPresentingVC:[Utility topViewController]
                  inView:view
                 atFrame:frame
           withDirection:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny];
```

**A few notes:**

- This code will work 1 to N times of opening & closing the popover but it will always eventually crash as of iOS 17. The crash always seems to happen when I open and close the popover quickly in succession.
- `frame` and `view` are always populated with the correct values, and `volumeVC` and `presentingVC` are always non-nil when I print them out in the `Utility::showDialogiPad` dialog method.
- When it crashes, the output of the debug statements in `+ (UIViewController*)topViewController` are:

```
Utility::topViewController(): topVC is: <UITabBarController: 0x7fc22d81ae00>
Utility::topViewController(): In loop, topVC is: <VolumeVC: 0x7fc22d01f460>, countLoops is: 0
```

- The main window of the app is a UITabBarController with a UISplitViewController in each tab.
- This app does not have multiple scenes in it nor does it use UIWindowScene.
- I know `keyWindow` is deprecated as of iOS 13. When I replace the `topViewController` code with the following:

```
+ (UIViewController*)topViewController {
    UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].connectedScenes.allObjects.firstObject;
    UIViewController *topVC = windowScene.windows.firstObject.rootViewController;    
    return topVC;
}
```

It will work 1 to N times but eventually it will crash with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7ff05c156890>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'
```

Thanks for any assistance with this.

Comment: The proper way to get the correct root view controller from some view controller is `self.view.window.rootViewController`. No need to access anything via the App Delegate, keyWindow, window scene, or shared UIApplication. This gets the correct root view even if your app has multiple scenes on display at the same time. Then you can walk up the chain of `presentedViewController` to find the top-most view controller.

Comment: You may wish to rethink your setup then. Only a view controller should present other view controllers. Something derived from NSObject should not do anything related to the UI. At most it should pass a message (probably via delegate or NotificationCenter), that it has a message or an event took place. Let the view controller decide how to handle that (such as presenting an alert).

Comment: So the error is that in `+showDialogiPad: fromPresentingVC:...` `contentVC` ==  `presentingVC`. It's hard to tell why, but since showing/dimissing (especially with `animated` true) takes "times", and unless you reach `completion` the next line of code might be called before the completion ends. I think that's your issue issue. A race condition

Comment: @Larme I think you are correct about the race condition. It looks like the view controller ("volumeVC") has not been dismissed completely by the time I try to present it again - so "volumeVC" incorrectly becomes the top most view controller as I am trying to present it again.  Are there ways to wait for the view controller to be completely dismissed in the completion block?

Comment: You can always test `[Utility topViewController] == volumeVC` before calling the method. For the rest, it's hard to tell I guess... You get the error by spamming the button to show the volume VC. Avoid spamming the button? Disable it if needed, or skip its action? Make a `completion` on your method to match the `completion:` of `presentViewController:animated:completion:`?

Comment: @Larme Adding a check to see if the presentingViewController == contentViewController seems to prevent the race condition and thus prevents the crash.

Comment: Indeed, but it's rather a bandaid fix than a real fix.

Comment: I agree @Larme I'm continuing to research a way to wait for completion of dismissal of the popover view controller.